# передача аргументов в multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing, pool

Есть код:

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product
import time

username = 'ivan'

my_items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def printing(username,my_items):
    print (username)
    print(my_items)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(printing, product(username, my_items))
```

по задумке, код должен для каждого итема в my_items выполнить функцию printing() с одним и тем же аргументом username, и сделать это одновременно в 4 процесса.
То есть по моей задумке результат должен выглядеть так:

```
ivan
1
ivan
2
ivan
3
ivan
4
ivan
5
ivan
6
ivan
7
ivan
8
ivan
9
```

а по факту код выдает результат:

```
i
1
i
2
i
3
i
4
i
5
i
etc...
```

и видимо по очереди, друг за другом. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results = pool.starmap(printing, product([username], my_items))
```

Comment: отлично, то что нужно! для теста добавил в функцию time.sleep(10), и результат функции увидел только спустя 32 секунды, почему такая задержка и процессы не выполняются параллельно?

Comment: @babyborn во-первых, если бы они не выполнялись параллельно, то результат вы бы увидели через 100 секунд. Во-вторых, вы создаёте пул из 4 процессов, соответственно сначала параллельно выполняются 4 функции `printing`, потом ещё 4 и потом оставшиеся 2. Каждая группа выполняется с задержкой в 10 секунд, три группы, итого 30 секунд плюс пара секунд накладных расходов на запуск процессов.